# Lua NodeMCU cron | list all crontables

Tags: lua, cron, nodemcu

I just want to know how to find/create a function to list all crontables already scheduled in NodeMCU.

(http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/cron/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is currently not available. There's a discussion about that at https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1751.

Answer (score 0):

Solved on github by https://github.com/djphoenix

```
>>>>>
Hi there.
So, there is some issues with it.
Now, schedule string description (like 0 1 * * *) is being parsed once you call :schedule method, and stored in packed bitmask format. There is difficult thing to process it back to string.
So list of entries without something that describing them is totally unusable (correct me if I wrong).

As module initiator and maintainer I prefer to keep it simple as possible, but if we can make it better - this is good :)
```